# PhoneGap Create project button does nothing

Tags: cordova, phonegap-desktop-app, phonegap

I installed PhoneGap desktop (version 0.4.4) on Windows 10, and am trying to create a new "hello world" project.

When I click the Create Project button, nothing happens, no error message.

[image: button does nothing]

Apparently after clicking create project it should switch to a new screen showing the project with a green play arrow as shown here: http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/3-create-your-app/desktop/

Any ideas?

Comment: Some times i get "the selected folder does not contain config.xml file"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/issues/793) is an issue that i found.

According to that you need to use V 0.4.3 till V 0.4.4 fix

> ... In the meantime I'd suggest you use 0.4.3 until we can figure out what is going on here.

Version history can be found [Here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/releases).

**[Attention]**

In my experience, you need to first uninstall the 0.4.4 version and then install the 0.4.3. otherwise it may not work.

**[Update]**
Problem Fixed.

According to the [issue](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/issues/793), Problem solved [at](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/issues/793#issuecomment-298404053)

**Reason**:

> For 0.4.4 I forgot to include a new dependency that we added for this
>   release, Mac was unaffected due to the differences in how we bundle
>   the packaged app. But this was only affecting version 0.4.4 for
>   Windows.

Comment: yep worked downloading version 0.4.3 https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/releases